# Which techniques used to streaming realtime gps data to webclient?

Tags: websocket, real-time, long-polling

I'm working on tracking car location realtime.

My backend server continuously received gps data from device on the car.

The gps data and the frequecy of data flow is huge.

I'm working on chose a right tech to stream data from server to webclient to 
real time draw position of car.

Currenty, i use websocket to stream data from backend to web client. But the performance is not good enough and i need to scale up.

Since my system is one way direction data flow from backend to web client.

I'm consider chose Server-Sent Events vs web socket.

Please give me some technology to handle my situation?

Thanks

Comment: If you think websocket is not good enough, then there is nothing that is good enough

Comment: My system work nomaly in one way direction. the server sent gps data to client at realtime to draw car position.

Answer (score 0):

You can continuously query the GPS data from cars using the [Stride API](http://www.stride.io), which is typically used to analyze streams of hundreds to hundreds of thousands of events per second for realtime analytics application development like the use case you mentioned, all without having to build or manage any realtime data infrastructure, so long as you're okay with using a SaaS product here.

Check out the [Stride technical docs](http://www.stride.io) for some examples. What you're trying to do here could easily be done with a small amount of code using the Stride API, though.